# IE Conditional operator: OR ... if is greater than ie9 or not IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I want to only include history and ajaxify if the browser is ie9 or greater, OR *is not* ie:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/history.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/ajaxify.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

How can I use the OR operator to say this:

`<!--[if gte IE 9 | !IE ]>` ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This worked:

```
    <!--[if gte IE 9 | !IE ]><!-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/history.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/ajaxify.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Technically, that's malformed HTML. (Since this is probably in your `<head>` then it probably won't have any ill effects in any browsers.) To make it valid HTML, insert a line containing just `<!--` between the last script tag and the endif.

Comment: Nevermind - apparently that's the standard way of doing it +1

Comment: According to the W3C validator this does indeed validate as proper HTML since `<!--efpewkoewfke><!-->` is a valid HTML comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the or operator is: `|`. You can check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) for further information on conditional comments.