# Conditional comment to include content where IE > 8 or !IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

On my website I have found that web fonts look really nasty on older versions of Internet Explorer, so I decided to use conditional commenting. Given that IE10+ no longer supports conditional comments I thought that the following might work:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]> -->
<link blah... />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Whilst this comment is behaving properly in IE7 and IE8, it does not seem to be working properly in IE9 (under simulation mode in IE10). The text `-->` is shown at the very start of the page.

The following conditional comment doesn't exhibit this behaviour:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link blah... />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

How can I reliably perform this conditional inclusion where `!IE or IE > 8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure how I missed this, but this question has already been asked before here on StackOverflow. I guess my initial search criteria wasn't good enough.

As per the following answer:
[IE Conditional operator: OR ... if is greater than ie9 or not IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461970/ie-conditional-operator-or-if-is-greater-than-ie9-or-not-ie#answer-16462168)

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link blah... />
<!--<![endif]-->
```