# Basic conditional statement in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I have three stylesheets; one for IE7, one for IE8 and one for IE9+ / Firefox / Chrome.

I want to use conditional statements to link each of these to my document. I have written these statements:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <link type="text/css" href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
   <link type="text/css" href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if ?????]>
   <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<![endif]-->
```

I am unsure of what to write in the `if` statement of the final conditional. I need something like:

```
<!--[if IE 9+ | !IE>
```

Which would mean `IF IE9+ or NOT IE`.

Is this achievable using conditionals?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

`gt` means "greater than", `gte` means "greater than or equal".

**Edit**

from [IE Conditional operator: OR ... if is greater than ie9 or not IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461970/ie-conditional-operator-or-if-is-greater-than-ie9-or-not-ie)

```
<!--[if gte IE 9 | !IE ]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks, but from testing this it doesn't seem to work on Firefox. The get IE 9 only registers on IE; I need some form of conditional that will work on Firefox.

Comment: Try using just first part of solution which says greater than 8, and `gt IE 8` is supported

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   // ie 8 stuff
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
   // ie 7 stuff
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !(IE)]><!--> i am not ie <!--<![endif]-->
```